# PhpMyAdmin: How to find the foreign key that is missing in the parent table?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-key-relationship

In a mySQL database I have two populated tables. Their structures are as in the image. When trying to relate them on **idArticol** (in PhpMyAdmin), an error appears: "Relation could not be added". I have more than 6000 records in each table. Apparently, the error comes from a missing foreign key from the parent table. Is there an SQL command that can help me find this missing key?

[image]

Comment: You can run "show engine innodb status;" - its output contains section "latest foreign key error" which might tell you more about FK troubles, but if it is really only missing row, then the query in answer is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the missing key by using this command

`SELECT * FROM userart WHERE idArticol NOT IN (SELECT idArticol FROM articol)`

This will give you all entrys in userart having an idArticol that is not in articol.idArticol

Comment: If you need to do it for lot of records, it is possible to rewrite this to left join, but for few thousands it won't make big difference.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Pinguin895! Your answer solved my problem! Much obliged!